# Binding VisualState to the ViewModel in Universal Windows 10 Apps

Tags: mvvm, win-universal-app, windows-10, visualstatemanager

I used to use a custom Blend behavior to bind an enum on the ViewModel to `VisualState`'s that were named the same as the enum enumerations.

However after including references and then including the `using`s, it seems the Bahaviors SDK is not currently supported.

What is the current best way to change VisualState in a MVVM way in a Windows 10 Universal App?

Comment: Blend SDK is supported. Make sure you use the one in 8.1.

Comment: Which one? There are no results on NuGet or when searching for VS extensions. This is the most recent one online but it is dated 2010 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801

Comment: Go to Blend and add a for example, GoToStateAction. Blend will then be added to your project automatically.

Comment: Hmm, OK I got it working - I found the 'Behavior SDK' in the references menu and tried it before but it didn't work first time around (crashed Blend) however I tried again and it works now (takes a while to load up the behaviors). Also the `Behavior<T>` base class was missing which made me think that it hadn't properly imported - I had to implement a behavior from `DependencyObject, IBehavior` from scratch but it works now.

Comment: Yeah there's no behavior base class anymore, you will have to use that Interface instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Behavior SDK" can be included by right-clicking on References -> Add Reference -> Universal Windows -> Extensions -> Behavior SDK.

Some of the APIs have been changed, so `Behavior<T>` is not there to inherit from (use `DependencyObject, IBehavior` instead and implement the `IBehavior` interface). Also `VisualStateUtilities.TryFindNearestStatefulControl` is now `VisualStateUtilities.FindNearestStatefulControl`. When I imported my old behaviors and couldn't resolve the references even with the Behavior SDK referenced, it made me think that the imports had not worked (especially since there is a warning about importing the Behavior SDK which claims it might not work - the link to find out more information is dead which hardly inspired confidence!).